# Python - Connect to IMAP through Socks

Tags: python, imap, socks

I'm looking for solution connect to IMAP using Socks proxy. The most elegant way that I found it's a wrapper of PySocks of IMAP4 lib (you can find gist with this code here: https://gist.github.com/sstevan/efccf3d5d3e73039c21aa848353ff52f).

The problem that I couldn't make it works in python3. For me it looks like there is an issue with inherit:

**Main script calls SocksIMAP4SSL wrapper**

```
    mailbox = SocksIMAP4SSL(host=imap_server, port=imap_port,
                            proxy_addr=proxy_addr, proxy_port=proxy_port, proxy_type=proxy_type)
```

**Implementation of init of SocksIMAP4SSL**

```
    def __init__(self, host='', port=IMAP4_SSL_PORT, keyfile=None, certfile=None, ssl_context=None, proxy_addr=None,
                 proxy_port=None, rdns=True, username=None, password=None, proxy_type="socks5"):
        .......
        SocksIMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, proxy_addr=proxy_addr, proxy_port=proxy_port,
                            rdns=rdns, username=username, password=password, proxy_type=proxy_type)
```

**Implementation of init of SocksIMAP4**

```
    def __init__(self, host, port=IMAP4_PORT, proxy_addr=None, proxy_port=None,
                 rdns=True, username=None, password=None, proxy_type="socks5"):

        self.proxy_addr = proxy_addr
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        self.rdns = rdns
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.proxy_type = SocksIMAP4.PROXY_TYPES[proxy_type.lower()]

        IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
```

When I run this code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lavidaloca/Programming/Projects/twitter_checkmat/twitter.py", line 691, in <module>
    hotmail = Hotmail('similargatorade3@hotmail.com', 'C9C48RyO', proxy)
  File "/Users/lavidaloca/Programming/Projects/twitter_checkmat/hotmail.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.mail = SocksIMAP4SSL(host=self.imap_server, port=self.imap_port, proxy_addr=proxy.host, proxy_port=proxy.port, username=proxy.login, password=proxy.password)
  File "/Users/lavidaloca/Programming/Projects/twitter_checkmat/hotmail.py", line 59, in __init__
    SocksIMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, proxy_addr=proxy_addr, proxy_port=proxy_port,
  File "/Users/lavidaloca/Programming/Projects/twitter_checkmat/hotmail.py", line 34, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
TypeError: open() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

It looks like by someway original **init** method of IMAP4 library receives init args of subclasses.

I'll be appreciate for your help if you give me idea how I can fix this code or give me another solution for make connection to imap over socks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: My bad. Will update post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python `imaplib` module changed in Python 3.9, and the `SocksIMAP4` module hasn't been updated.  That's the danger in dinking with the internals of a module.  You can try to hack it by adding a third parameter to `SocksIMAP4.open` that you ignore.

You might also file a bug report with the `SocksIMAP4` folks.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, for now I just added one more parameter to SocksIMAP4.open and it works